# barplot overwrites on axis names when changing axis limits

Tags: r, bar-chart, names

I have the following data frame:

```
datatest=as.data.frame(matrix(c(4,5,-10,2,-3,7),6,1))
rownames(datatest)=paste0("row",1:6)
```

and I have the following barplot

```
barplot(datatest$V1,horiz = TRUE,names=rownames(datatest),las=1,col="black")
```

[original barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iF8w.png)

However, when I change the axis, the plot is overwriting on the name like this :

```
barplot(datatest$V1,horiz = TRUE,names=rownames(datatest),las=1,col="black",xlim=c(-5,5))
```

[barplot with axis changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMsbR.png)

How can I do to make the barplot stop before the names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "xpd=F" option. Take a look at the [help page for barplot](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/barplot.html).